# chat app with node.js and socket.io

Tags: node.js, socket.io

I'm trying to create a chat app with node.js and socket.io

This is my app.js with addresses scripts

```
var express = require('express'),
    app = express(),
    server = require('http').createServer(app),
    io = require('socket.io').listen(server);

server.listen(3000);

app.get('/', function(req, res){
    res.sendfile(__dirname + '/game.php');
});

io.sockets.on('connection', function(socket){
    socket.on('send message', function(data){
        io.sockets.emit('new message', data);
    });
});
```

With .html everything works well

But when i change it to .php  instead of loading the page it starts to downloading it

on " localhost:3000"

What should i change to make it work?

If you need the game.php code ask me to post it.

**UPDATE:**
edited this part

```
app.get('/', function(req, res) {
  res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'text/html');
  res.sendfile(__dirname + '/game.php');
});
```

and now it gives me

```
ReferenceError: text is not defined
    at C:\Users\Mojtaba\Desktop\chat\app.js:9:33
    at callbacks (C:\Users\Mojtaba\Desktop\chat\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:161:37)
    at param (C:\Users\Mojtaba\Desktop\chat\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:135:11)
    at pass (C:\Users\Mojtaba\Desktop\chat\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:142:5)
    at Router._dispatch (C:\Users\Mojtaba\Desktop\chat\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:170:5)
    at Object.router (C:\Users\Mojtaba\Desktop\chat\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:33:10)
    at next (C:\Users\Mojtaba\Desktop\chat\node_modules\express\node_modules\connect\lib\proto.js:190:15)
    at Object.expressInit [as handle] (C:\Users\Mojtaba\Desktop\chat\node_modules\express\lib\middleware.js:31:5)
    at next (C:\Users\Mojtaba\Desktop\chat\node_modules\express\node_modules\connect\lib\proto.js:190:15)
    at Object.query [as handle] (C:\Users\Mojtaba\Desktop\chat\node_modules\express\node_modules\connect\lib\middleware\query.js:44:5
```

Comment: Is your `game.php` an actual PHP script or just plain HTML?

Comment: Then that's your problem, you're using the wrong tool. Node does not know how to read PHP. Your game logic should be implemented in JavaScript.

Comment: other than game logic have to use PHP for connecting to SQL,session  and etc.if i don't use PHP how can i do this things? how will you do this?

Comment: In JavaScript. There should be modules out there to do what you want in NodeJS. Or, if you want to do it in PHP, use a PHP-capable web server (Apache, Nginx, Lighttp...)

Answer (score 0):

What determines if a browser shows a file as a downloaded attachement or if it should open it directly is the Content-Disposition HTTP header.

Try to add this before sending the file:

res.setHeader('Content-Disposition', 'inline');

and now the browser should no longer treat the file as an attachment. What is probably happening is that express is looking at the extension of the file and as it does not recognize the PHP extension it sends the file back as an attachment.

But the opened file should not display as you want in the browser, as the browser cannot interpret PHP. PHP files are meant to be interpreted in the backend and not sent to the browser.

You can use PHP as a view engine in express using for example [php-node](https://npmjs.org/package/php-node), buy i don't think it's a very frequent combination.

The default view engine for express is [jade](http://jade-lang.com/), [mustache](https://npmjs.org/package/mustache) is also frequently mentioned as well as [handlebars](http://handlebarsjs.com/).

If you prefer your templating engine on the client side instead of the server side, check [angular.js](http://angularjs.org/).

Before going on it's important to understand that sending PHP files to the browser is not the solution for the problem being solved, read some an [article](http://openmymind.net/2012/5/30/Client-Side-vs-Server-Side-Rendering/) or two first on the differences between server side and client side templating.